# Parameterized call of swing instance

Tags: java, swing, jpa

My problem is the following: I have a Java Swing application that uses database connection via JPA. The startup process is slow due to the authentication onto the database. Furthermore this application, when being closed, has to authenticate again when being opened. This is unsatisfactory.

I thought of a workaround where the Swing instance is being held in idle instead of being closed. When another call occurs, the instance opens with the according parameters. An example of this is MS Word ( the inital startup is slow, but when an instance is already running, the current instance is being overwritten with the current call instead of creating a new instance).

Does anyone have any idea how this could work? A starting point or a tutorial where the above is being shown would be helpful.

Comment: *"Does anyone have any idea how this could work?"* [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) has inbuilt support for this type of thing using the [`SingleInstanceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html) which: *"..allow(s) applications launched under Java Web Start to register themselves as singletons, and to be passed in new parameter sets when user attempts to launch new instances of them."* The app. decides what to do when passed new parameters (e.g. change the details of current instance, open new..)

Comment: thanks, that gives me something to work with